# Can the DocuSign Connect (webhook) module send updates to non public URLs?

Tags: docusignapi

I know DocuSign can send signed PDF and other stuff to a public URL using the DocuSign Connect module.

I want to know whether they will send to our own server listner page.  Will DocuSign will send signed information to non-public URL

Comment: I added info about ngrok to my answer. Also, welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote all useful answers (including those to others' questions). And "accept" (check) the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

DocuSign Connect and eventNotifications (same notification mechanism, different subscription process), will send the notifications to any url that is available via the public internet.

There are different meanings for "non-public url." Your server/listener's url does not have to linked to by any other page, it does not have to be in the Google database, it can use long, obscure strings in the url, etc. But it has to be reachable via the public internet.

So if your listener is accessible via the public internet, you're golden.

Other options:

- Put your listener on your company's [dmz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) where it will be accessible from the internet and also have some access to your internal systems.
- Put your listener behind your firewall and open a "pinhole" in your firewall to enable the incoming connection requests. [DocuSign publishes the ip ranges it uses](https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/) so you can limit the size of the opening in your firewall
- Create a server/listener "gateway" on the public internet that your internal servers can connect to. Eg, start up a listener using Heroku, Azure, etc. I suggest their PAAS services.
- Investigate [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/), and this [related blog post](https://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/38-You-may-not-need-localtunnel-or-ngrok.html)

Also:

- Remember that your listener must accept requests via https. Only https is used for notifications by the DocuSign production platforms.

See the [DocuSign webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) for more info.